# I want to instead of showing every Pivot High/Low with the triangle, if i check the box it show just the last recent high and recent low

Tags: pine-script

showRecentOnly = input(title="Pivots Highs & Lows", defval=false)

```
lb = input(defval=5, title='Left Bars')
rb = input(defval=5, title='Right Bars')
 
mb = lb + rb + 1

highestbars_1 = ta.highestbars(mb)
iff_1 = highestbars_1 == -lb ? high[lb] : na
plotshape(not na(high[mb]) ? iff_1 : na, title='Triangle Pivot High', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 60), size=size.tiny, offset=-lb)

lowestbars_1 = ta.lowestbars(mb)
iff_2 = lowestbars_1 == -lb ? low[lb] : na
plotshape(not na(low[mb]) ? iff_2 : na, title='Triangle Pivot Low', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 60), size=size.tiny, offset=-lb)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are going to plot the triangles for only last high and low, then we will have to delete them too when new high/low occurs and it is not possible to delete shapes using pinescript. We can only delete lines and boxes etc. So here I have done a version where you can click a checkbox to show line for latest pivot high lows and uncheck to see how it was previously

```
//@version=5
indicator("test",overlay=true)
lb = input(defval=5, title='Left Bars')
rb = input(defval=5, title='Right Bars')
showlastonly=input(defval=false)
mb = lb + rb + 1

var lasthighbarindex=0
var lastlowbarindex=0
var h=0.0
var l=0.0

highestbars_1 = ta.highestbars(mb)
plotshape((not showlastonly) and (highestbars_1 == -lb), title='Triangle Pivot High', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 60), size=size.tiny, offset=-lb)
if (highestbars_1 == -lb)
    lasthighbarindex:=lb
    h:=high[lb]
else
    lasthighbarindex:=lasthighbarindex+1
lowestbars_1 = ta.lowestbars(mb)
plotshape((not showlastonly) and (lowestbars_1 == -lb), title='Triangle Pivot Low', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 60), size=size.tiny, offset=-lb)
if (lowestbars_1 == -lb)
    lastlowbarindex:=lb
    l:=low[lb]
else
    lastlowbarindex:=lastlowbarindex+1
if showlastonly and barstate.islast
    linehigh=line.new(bar_index-lasthighbarindex,h,bar_index,h,color=color.red)
    linelow=line.new(bar_index-lastlowbarindex,l,bar_index,l,color=color.green)
    line.delete(id=linehigh[1])
    line.delete(id=linelow[1])
```

[Before checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ISrQ.png) [After checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W2sL.png)